# Perl Replace Capture Group With Length of Capture Group

Tags: regex, perl

Given :

```
my $str = "foo95285734776bar"; 
$str =~ s/([0-9]{2,4})/_????_/g;
```

What single regex where '????' is the length of $1 can produce output "foo_4__4__3_bar" ?

That is, where "9528" is replaced with "_4_", "5734" with "_4_", and the remaining "776" with "_3_".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`/e` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) to add Perl code into the substitution part that is then evaled.

```
my $str = "foo95285734776bar";
$str =~ s/([0-9]{2,4})/'_' . length($1) . '_'/ge;

print $str;
```

Will output

```
foo_4__4__3_bar
```

Note that you now need a full Perl expression there. That's why you have to actually quote and concatenate the underscores.

From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

> A `/e` will cause the replacement portion to be treated as a full-fledged Perl expression and evaluated right then and there. It is, however, syntax checked at compile-time. A second e modifier will cause the replacement portion to be evaled before being run as a Perl expression.

Comment: Neat, thanks ! Will accept answer unless someone can provide a non-eval method.

Comment: @robut note that this is not actually _string eval_. It's a regular, built-in feature of the Perl regex engine. See `perl -MO=Concise -e 'my $str = "foo95285734776bar"; $str =~ s/([0-9]{2,4})/"_" . length($1) . "_"/ge;'` See my update with more documentation. It's not a bad `eval`.

Comment: @robut, This solution does not involve `eval` (unlike `/ee`).  `/e` causes the source file to be treated as code (not the value of some variable), so there's no security issue. Anyone who can change your source file can already make your script do anything. For example, `s{foo}{bar}g` is equivalent to `s{foo}{ qq{bar} }eg`; both evaluate a double-quoted string on replacement.

Comment: I came to the question when wanting to craft some eval in perl. Maybe somebody can point me to place in perl docs where dot (.) operator is described, I could not find it in https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html, only some other places on the web via search.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov the `.` is the concatenation operator. See https://perlmaven.com/string-operators for a good tutorial, and https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators for the general description in the docs. It's not much there, because it just adds two strings together.

Comment: Thank you. My mistake I searched for 'concatenation' in docs, but it's 'concatenates' - pitty I have not guessed to search for beginning of the word!